# git игнорировать файлы в удаленном репозитории

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

Не пойму как добиться того, что бы при удалении файла в локальном репозитории, они оставались на удаленном?

Comment: Одна из главных задач git - это как раз обеспечивать одинаковость всех репозиториев. С какой целью вы хотите выполнить заявленное в вопросе?

Comment: Допустим есть некоторые каталоги с файлами, которые мне не хотелось бы тянуть на свой ПК, для экономии места к примеру.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй использовать команду

`git update-index --assume-unchanged папка_с_файлом/имя_файла.расширение`

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Это команда добавляет запись в файл .gitignore  ?

Comment: @8toni8, эта команда делает локальные изменения файла невидимыми для git. Очень не советую ей пользоваться без тщательного изучения инструкции, иначе её поведение может оказаться для вас крайне неожиданным.

Comment: Можете привести небольшой пример, такой неожиданности?